# Remove legend in multiple plots?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make multiplots containing 5 barcharts (with 2 colomns and 3 rows) I want the legend is appeared in the rows 3, column 2. And also, I want to change label from (A, B, C..) into (m/z=450.02 RT 9.52, m/z 500.07 RT 10, ...)  that will appear in the up-right position of each plot. 
Also, I want to add error bar in the first chart with data SD, but I couldn't add them in the plot. 
Please help me to solve this plots. Thank you!

Here's my console:

```
data <- data.frame(group = c("B. mamane+SAHAall","B. mamane+SAHAprod","Untreated B. mamane","B. mamane+VSall","B. mamane+VSprod"),
               intensity = c(7378298.69217025,9009027.95021888,11106773.0180047,3010750.725502,25794620.5038354), 
               sd = c(2554669.97449261,1054643.80319534,4936955.54885355, 1606982.34241596, 9975537.82883142))
```

head(data)

```
data1 <- data.frame(group = c("B. mamane+SAHAall","B. mamane+SAHAprod","Untreated B. mamane","B. mamane+VSall","B. mamane+VSprod"),
                intensity = c(1089586.025,
                              1622944.618,
                              1466859.571,
                              1213772.715,
                              9310160.875))
data2 <- data.frame(group = c("B. mamane+SAHAall","B. mamane+SAHAprod","Untreated B. mamane","B. mamane+VSall","B. mamane+VSprod"),
                intensity = c(1196693.956,
                              1742096.027,
                              1545728.252,
                              1307935.409,
                              9569069.002)) 

data2 <- data.frame(group = c("B. mamane+SAHAall","B. mamane+SAHAprod","Untreated B. mamane","B. mamane+VSall","B. mamane+VSprod"),
                intensity = c(1196693.956,
                              1742096.027,
                              1545728.252,
                              1307935.409,
                              9569069.002))
data3 <- data.frame(group = c("B. mamane+SAHAall","B. mamane+SAHAprod","Untreated B. mamane","B. mamane+VSall","B. mamane+VSprod"),
                intensity = c(106964005.1,
                              92622841.82,
                              122723308,
                              159793488.3,
                              153196930.7))
data4 <- data.frame(group = c("B. mamane+SAHAall","B. mamane+SAHAprod","Untreated B. mamane","B. mamane+VSall","B. mamane+VSprod"),
                intensity = c(770606573.5,
                              613182573.3,
                              780913983.6,
                              829523587.7,
                              809287616.6))
```

## making plot

```
    p <-ggplot(data, aes(group, y=intensity)) +
 geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill =group ))+theme(legend.position = "none")
 theme_minimal()+
 theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
 axis.text.x=element_blank(),
 axis.ticks.x=element_blank())

        p1 <-ggplot(data1, aes(group, y=intensity)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill =group ))+
   theme_minimal()+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
       axis.text.x=element_blank(),
       axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
     p2 <-ggplot(data2, aes(group, y=intensity)) +
   geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill =group ))+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
          axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
    p3 <-ggplot(data3, aes(group, y=intensity)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill =group ))+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
    p4 <-ggplot(data4, aes(group, y=intensity)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill =group ))+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
    library(grid)
plot_grid(p,p1,p2,p3,p4, labels=c("A", "B","C","D","E"), ncol = 2, nrow = 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data0 <- data

library(plyr)
all<- ldply(0:4, function(x){
          tmp <- get(paste0("data", x))
          tmp$gp <- x
          tmp
       })

ggplot(all, aes(group, intensity, fill=group)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill =group )) + 
  geom_errorbar(data=all[all$gp==0, ], aes(
                ymin=intensity-sd, ymax=intensity+sd)) +
  facet_wrap(~gp, scales="free", ncol=2) +
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: add `width=.1` in the `geom_errobar` function. Good to get acquainted with [plotting means and error bars](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_(ggplot2)/)